# action after button click in scroll menu in html with using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, href

I have array of two elements in flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import psycopg2
import numpy as np


app = Flask(__name__)

d = [10,12,16,17]

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', d=d, length=len(d))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And also I have Vertical Scroll Menu in html:

```
<h1>Vertical Scroll Menu</h1>

<div class="vertical-menu">
  <a href="#" class="active">change number</a>
        {% for i in range(length) %}
            <a href="#">select number{{d[i]}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
<input type="text" name="name" required="required">
```

I need to insert number in array into output form after href clicking.How should I solve my problem?

Comment: "I need to insert number in array into output form after href clicking" Could you elaborate. Are you using the POST method on the form? GET method? Only js popup? ...

Comment: I tried to use methods="POST","GET", but I cannot understand clearly how it works

Answer (score 0):

Demo HTML

```html
<form action="{{url_for('process_number')}}" method="POST">
<select name="number">
    {% for i in d %}
            <option value="{{d[i]}}">{{d[i]}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Flask function

```py
@app.route('/process-number', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_number():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_number = request.form['number']
        # do what you want
```

Comment: Thank you.But it does not work at the second step.

Comment: Retry, i fixed it